# TransformerPageController is not working .when I controlled it from AwesomeSlide in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, uipageviewcontroller

> when I try to control the TransformerPageView from the awesome slide it not working. and at the same time, TransformerPageView does not work on swipe. if I removed the controller from TransformerPageView the TransformerPageView working perfectly fine

TransformerPageController controller = TransformerPageController();

```
 TransformerPageView(
                          //
                          loop: false,
                          onPageChanged: (index) {
                            control.chnage1(index.toDouble());
                            //  setState(() {  });
                            valuess = index;
                            //    moveWidget(index);
                            //  _currentIndex = index;
                          },
                          pageController: controller,
                          transformer: DeepthPageTransformer(),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Stack(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Stack(
                                            children: [
                                              Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                                                child: Hero(
                                                  tag: 'hero1',
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      decoration:
                                                          BoxDecoration(),
                                                      //   color:Colors.deepOrange,
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        //  alignment: Alignment.center,

                                                        children: [
                                                          Align(
                                                            alignment: Alignment
                                                                .center,
                                                            child: SizedBox(
                                                                height: 200,
                                                                width: 200,
                                                                child: control
                                                                            .counter1
                                                                            .value ==
                                                                        0.0
                                                                    ? Container()
                                                                    : Image
                                                                        .asset(
                                                                        Constants.levelImages[control
                                                                            .counter1
                                                                            .value
                                                                            .toInt()],
                                                                      )),
                                                          ),
                                                          Padding(
                                                            padding:
                                                                const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .all(12.0),
                                                            child: Align(
                                                              alignment:
                                                                  Alignment
                                                                      .center,
                                                              child: Text(
                                                                Constants
                                                                        .levelname[
                                                                    control
                                                                        .counter1
                                                                        .value
                                                                        .toInt()],
                                                                textAlign:
                                                                    TextAlign
                                                                        .center,
                                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                                    color: Colors
                                                                        .white,
                                                                    fontSize:
                                                                        15),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: 6,
                        ),


 AwesomeSlide(
                            activeLineStroke: 1,
                            value: control.counter1.value,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 5,
                            thumbSize: 110.0,
                            inactiveLineColor: Colors.white,
                            activeLineColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Material(
                              type: MaterialType.card,
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Image.asset("assets/images/SliderTop.png"),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              print("value print  $value");

                              controller.animateToPage(value.toInt(),
                                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                  curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                              setState(() {});
                              moveWidget(value.toInt());
                              //    setState(() {  });
                            }),
```